# Where I can find kARDTurnRequestUrl and kARDDefaultSTUNServerUrl in WebRTC iOS

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc

I am building an app using webrtc like this : https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-ios/blob/master/Lib/ARDAppClient.m

```
// TODO(tkchin): move these to a configuration object.
static NSString *kARDRoomServerHostUrl = @"https://apprtc.appspot.com";
static NSString *kARDRoomServerRegisterFormat = @"%@/join/%@";
static NSString *kARDRoomServerMessageFormat = @"%@/message/%@/%@";
static NSString *kARDRoomServerByeFormat = @"%@/leave/%@/%@";

static NSString *kARDDefaultSTUNServerUrl = @"stun:stun.l.google.com:19302";
// TODO(tkchin): figure out a better username for CEOD statistics.
static NSString *kARDTurnRequestUrl = @"https://computeengineondemand.appspot.com"
@"/turn?username=iapprtc&key=4080218913";
```

But I dont know how to change **kARDDefaultSTUNServerUrl** and **kARDTurnRequestUrl** to my server and I am not the person who deploy the server, too. He just give me the server url for join room. I changed **kARDRoomServerHostUrl** and the request is success.

The post request : https://myserver:443/join/roomID is work perfect. It return this json:

```
{
  "result": "SUCCESS",
  "params": {
    "room_link": "http://myserver:8080/r/1123123",
    "media_constraints": "{\"audio\": true, \"video\": {\"mandatory\": {}, \"optional\": [{\"minWidth\": \"1280\"}, {\"minHeight\": \"720\"}]}}",
    "warning_messages": [],
    "ice_server_transports": "",
    "callstats_params": "{\"appSecret\": \"none\", \"appId\": \"none\"}",
    "include_loopback_js": "",
    "messages": [],
    "bypass_join_confirmation": "false",
    "wss_url": "wss://myserver:8089/ws",
    "wss_post_url": "https://myserver:8089",
    "ice_server_url": "https://networktraversal.googleapis.com/v1alpha/iceconfig?key=none",
    "room_id": "1123123",
    "offer_options": "{}",
    "error_messages": [],
    "pc_constraints": "{\"optional\": []}",
    "is_loopback": "false",
    "pc_config": "{\"bundlePolicy\": \"max-bundle\", \"iceServers\": [{\"url\": \"stun:myserver:3478\", \"credential\": \"123456\"}, {\"url\": \"turn:10000@myserver:3478\", \"credential\": \"123456\"}], \"rtcpMuxPolicy\": \"require\"}",
    "turn_url": "http://myserver:3478/turn?username=80714691&key=123456",
    "is_initiator": "true",
    "client_id": "80714691"
  }
}
```

Can anybody help me, please. Thank you.
*Sorry about my poor english.

Comment: Can you clarify what are you trying to achieve more clearly ?

Answer (score 0):

Those URLS are retrieved in the ARDAppClient's init method.
When you instantiate ARDAppClient with it's delegate check the method. 
You can find the url there. 
It's static NSString * const kARDIceServerRequestUrl = @"https://appr.tc/params";

Hope this is what you were looking for.. :)